# How to change text on cart / checkout buttons

Tags: checkout

I want to change the text on the buttons on my cart page

could some refer me to the correct file and the changes i need to make. I am happy with the style - its a simple change from 'card payment checkout' to 'secure checkout'

here's the info from inspect element of current buttons.

https://www.installaudio.co.uk/checkout/onepage/';">Card Payment Checkout

Card Payment Checkout

CSS path
body > div.wrapper > div > div.main-container.col1-layout > div > div > div > div.page-title.title-buttons > ul > li:nth-child(4) > button

help is much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If "Card Payment Checkout" is a custom payment method, you should be able to change the title of it via Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Payment Method -> title.

Otherwise you will need to find the template file in your theme that contains the text and either change the text there, or add a "translation" to your locale files.

Comment: Yes I need to find the template file as you suggest... Do you have any advice as to how to find the correct file to edit? (im learning)

Comment: If you have command line access change into your magento theme template folder and type grep -irl "Card Payment Checkout" * this will search your magento installation for all occurrences of the given text.

Comment: i have full access although ive never done command line access before - any other way?

Comment: Enable template hints (dev/test store only, not production!)